# Conflict with JQuery Scripts Slider & Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently designing a website for my dissertation which has to have some JQuery in it, currently have a responsive navigation which uses Jquery and the flexslider which also uses jquery but when ran together they conflict.

The navigation code looks like this, which has to be in the body to work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

While the sliders code is here

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

Just need them both to function

Comment: I think this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> jQuery.noConflict(); </script>` is not valid, dont type any codes inside external resources tag, and, how do you decide that the jquery is conflicted or not ??

Comment: This is code I've used from another source so it should be fine, I just tried to add the noconflict to solve the issue

Comment: This was the original code <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

Comment: why dont just use 1 jquery?

Comment: kinda messing up the whole design of the site really need to implement this, is it because the script needs to be in the head?

Comment: No, you can embed jquery in `<body>` tag too, but If I were you, I will use only 1 jquery stable latest version that embeded in the `<head>`, How can one line `<script>` messing up whole design ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), which includes these examples:

Example: **Create a different alias** instead of jQuery to use in the rest of the script.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Example: Completely move jQuery to a **new namespace** in another object.

```
var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Result:

```
// Do something with the new jQuery
dom.query("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
// Do something with another version of jQuery
jQuery("div > p").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JQuery 1.7.2 should be backwards compatible with 1.6.2...

Comment: Did you also took out all the calls to jQuery.noConflict();?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes took out all the noconflict, the responsive navigation continues to work fine, but the flexslider code wont run so its just looks like a flat box without any of the functionality or images that it should have

Comment: Do you still have this function? jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();
});

Comment: Can you alter your question and post a simple html page with what you have?

Answer (score -1):

Having exactly the same issue... I think the moral of the story is that you cannot load two versions of jQuery and expect them to be compatible.

My shopping cart alert popup (the box that load to tell users they added stuff to the cart) stopped working... but the slider works fine.

But I'm really interested to find out if there is a solution to this.